# Notating function increase

Tags: functions, notation

Is there a way to formally notate the following statement?

> For a function $f(x)$, as $x$ increases, $f$ decreases, and as $x$ decreases, $f$ increases

Comment: Well you can say $f(x)$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't symbolic notation that I'm aware of, but typically the standard term is "$f(x)$ is a decreasing function", with "$f(x)$ is a strictly decreasing function" if $f(x)$ never "levels off" and has zero gradient.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like order-reversing / antitone function from [order theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory) point of view.